# How to Determine N of an M x N CSR Sparse Matrix

Tags: sparse-matrix, dimensions, csr

I have the CSR sparse matrix arrays representing an M x N matrix:

- data
- indoor
- indices

My question is how do I determine the original dimension N. I understand that indptr has a M + 1 entries, so M is easily determined. But I can't see how to determine N, unless the matrix is square (M = N).

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Kind regards

John

Comment: Which language?  For Python `scipy.sparse`, the matrix object has a `shape` parameter (just like the `numpy` arrays).  When creating the matrix from those inputs, without a shape specification, it just uses the maximum value of the `indices` array.

Answer (score 0):

This heavily depends on the implementation of CRS/CCS. As you have noticed, it is only possible to directly extract the number of rows `M` when using CRS (or the number of columns `N` when using CCS) if the matrix has `M * N` entries. I'll try to answer this using the *Eigen SparseMatrix* implementation in C++ as you didn't specify for which language.

To initialize a sparse matrix with Eigen, you must first define a container of triplets (which contain information of the value, row and index of a coefficient):

```
std::vector<Eigen::Triplet<double>> coefficients;
buildProblem(coefficients); //fills the vector according to problem
```

Then you must declare the sparse matrix for which must include the dimension of the matrix:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A(m,n);
A.setFromTriplets(coefficients.begin(), coefficients.end());
```

To retrieve the dimension, you can use these methods:

```
A.rows();
A.cols();
A.size(); // returns rows*cols

A.innerSize(); // returns minor dimension with respect to the storage order, i.e., the number of rows for a column-major matrix
A.outerSize(); // returns major dimension with respect to the storage order, i.e., the number of columns for a column-major matrix

A.nonZeros();
```